# How do I use strcasestr()?

Tags: c, string, gcc

I `#include <string.h>` but when I call `strcasestr(src, search);` I get the following error message `implicit declaration of function ‘strcasestr’`.  how to I compile: `gcc-4.6 -Wall -lsqlite3 -lunac -Werror -O2 -o foo.out foo.c` how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Windows; You simply don't use it, as Windows does not have such thing (maybe MingW provides it?, but that compiler produces far slower App for some reason).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As specified in the [corresponding manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasestr), since `strcasestr` is a nonstandard extension you must `#define _GNU_SOURCE` <del>before the `#include <string.h>`</del> before any `#include` (other files may already include `<string.h>`, thanks @Cubbi for pointing out this potential problem); this can also easily be accomplished by specifying `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on the compiler command line.

Comment: I added too the prototype function:`#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE       
char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);` and works fine now. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Jack, you do not need to (and should not) add the prototype. However, the define needs to be **before** the include.

Comment: Caveat: make sure that #define is the first line in the file. If you `#include <stdio.h>`, then `#define _GNU_SOURCE`, and then `#include <string.h>`, you won't get strcasestr because stdio.h already included string.h. The safe choice is compiling with -D_GNU_SOURCE.

Comment: I added that line as well, but still does not work. any help?

Comment: @Hefaz What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: CodeBlocks in Windows. I solved the problem by defining that function. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You must add:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before the `string.h` include, since the function is non-standard.