# Why is scanf not allowing any more input?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[100], b[100];
    char *ret;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", b);
    ret = strstr(a, b);
    if (ret != NULL)
        printf("its a substring");
    else
        printf("not a substring");
    return 0;
}
```

My aim was to check whether a substring is present in the parent string in the string or not. I learned about the `strstr()` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c).

I have previously used `%[^\n]s` in my codes before and they worked well.
But, in this case as soon as I hit return/enter after typing one string, the output is `not a substring`.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", a); scanf("%99[^\n]",  b);`

Comment: What is the input to your program? What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: Also, if you want to read a whole line I suggest you use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude input is a string(eg "karan singh" as the parent string and the substring is something like "sin").but as soon as I hit a newline character after "karan singh", the program gives me an output.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is very confusing :/

Comment: Why not use simply `scanf("%s", a);` ?

Comment: @JithinPavithran I want to have multiple words in my string. Simply %s won't allow that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first call to `scanf()` stops when it sees a newline (`'\n'`) but it's still in the input stream.
So, the second call fails immediately as it sees the (same) newline character.

You should always check the return value of `scanf()` calls for failure.

You can insert a `getchar();` call in between the `scanf()` calls to consume the newline character. Or better use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and handle the newline character.

---

This is how you could use `fgets()` in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
     char a[100], b[100];
     char *ret;
     if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin) == NULL) {
        /* error handling */
     }

     a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
     if (fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin) == NULL) {
       /* error handling */
     }

     b[strcspn(b, "\n")] = '\0';
     ret=strstr(a, b);
     if(ret!=NULL)
         printf("its a substring");
     else
         printf("not a substring");
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I was using fgets(), to solve a concatenation of strings question right before this question, but the problem was that the concatenation also had a newline character in between, so I switched to scanf.

Comment: Also, how do I use getchar() to consume the newline character?

Comment: `fgets()` approach is better. You can remove it using `strcspn()`: `a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';` and `b[strcspn(b, "\n")] = '\0';` after the calls to `fgets()` on `a` and `b`.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this for a beginner?Its very difficult to understand :/

Comment: @Karan what he said basically says `retrieve a string`, `search for the newline`, and `remove the newline`.

Comment: @KaranSingh You just have to read the documentation and do some examples to understand them better. I have updated the answer with how you could make use of `fgets()` and remove the newline character.

Comment: @MarkYisri Sorry, I have accidentally overwritten your edit suggestion (which is good) because I was editing at the same.

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf()` format you use `%[^\n]` does not have a trailing `s` and you should provide the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array. Since the array has a size of 100, you should specify `%99[^\n]`.

Furthermore, you must skip the newline between the 2 `%99[^\n]` otherwise the second conversion will fail since there would no characters different from `\n` to match.

Here is a simple correction using `scanf()`. *usr* has a good alternative using `fgets()` which is a simpler way to parse input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[100], b[100], c;

    if (scanf("%99[^\n]%c%99[^\n]", a, &c, b) == 3 && c == '\n') {
        if (strstr(a, b))
            printf("its a substring\n");
        else
            printf("not a substring\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the %99[^\n] part please?

Comment: why are you omitting the 's' (the specifier for a string)?

Comment: @KaranSingh: the `99` is the maximum number of characters to store into the array pointed to by the pointer argument (before the null terminator, so it is the buffer size - 1).

Comment: @KaranSingh: The `s` is an error: `%s` and `%[^\n]` are 2 different conversion specifiers. With your format string, `scanf()` tries to match an `s` after the end of the line and fails.