# How to read and extract specific text from a .txt file in c

Tags: c

I have been given an assignment to write a program in c that reads a c program and extract functions from it.Can anyone help?

```
>  #include<stdio.h>
>      #include<conio.h>
>      int c;
>      FILE *file; 
>      file = fopen("c.c", "r"); 
>      if (file) {
>         while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
>             putchar(c);
>         fclose(file); 
> 
>      }
```

Comment: Yes, if you have a specific problem with your current implementation.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @naccyde apologies! Better now?

Comment: That's a simple "read input and echo to output" program, far from a lexer/parser for the C language that would "extract functions" (function calls? prototypes? definitions?). Why the *conio.h*?

Comment: did you search for similar questions? seems like something that has been done

Comment: Smells like [LEX & YACC](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) to operate as lexer (tokenizer) and parser.

Comment: Please provide diverse sample input and describe what the reaction of your program should be or give desired output.

Comment: Lex & Yacc might be overkill for simple cases.

Comment: @SakethGangam worse, actually.  Your code will not compile because of the '>' chars and a '#incude' not at the start of a line.  Also, as commented above, your code does next-to-nothing.  If one was in a suspicious frame of mind, one might suspect that you found the first example of C file-handling you could get off the web and dumped it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will fine enough help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/easiest-way-to-get-files-contents-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c).

First of all if you want to read the c file, find your answer in the first link. Second of all after opening it from the first step, you should look for types (helping yourself with the second link): bool, int, void, ..., then you will save the line with a getline().

your getline should include the following if your c file is well indent :

- the type (including pointers if any),
- the name of the function,
- the parameters

Then from the **first** '{' you will find your function implementation. If there is any more loop inside your fonction, you have to count all the '{' in order to know where your function finishes by putting them in a LIFO.

You will have to do this until the end of the doc to know all the functions.

Comment: Anytime, if you have probleme implementing it ask for more !