# C: How to find that a certain number of characters are present in a string in any sequence?

Tags: c, string, loops, substring

So the given task is to make a function that checks for any string if

1. All 5 letters 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', and 'e' are included (in any
   sequence) and
2. The string 'abcde' is a substring of the given string.
   If 1 holds (but 2 does not), return 1.
   If both 1 and 2 holds, return 2.
   Otherwise, return 0.

Examples:

```
checkabcde(“someaxbxcxdxemm”) -> 1
checkabcde(“someOtherValue”) -> 0
checkabcde(“xyabcdeping”) -> 2
checkabcde(“someaxuxdxlxammabcde”) -> 2
```

In my approach I've been able to find that is the substring is "abcde" but unable to determine that the string contains 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' in any sequence

```
int checkabcde(char str[]) {

  char str2[] = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e'
  };

  char str3[5]; //to be filled with elements from str2 when found inconsecutive order

  int i, z, x, f;

  z = 0; //position for str3
  f = 0; //flag for similarity comparison of str2 and str3

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(str2); x++) {
      if (str[i] == str2[x]) {

        if ((str[i] == 'a') && (str[i + 1] == 'b') && (str[i + 2] == 'c') && (str[i + 3] == 'd') && (str[i + 4] == 'e')) {
          return 2;
        } else {

          if (str3[z] != str[z - 1]) {
            str3[z] = str2[x];
            z++;
          }

        }

      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      if (str2[i] == str3[x]) {
        f++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (f == 5) {
    return 1;
  } else if (f1 == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

edit: pointers not allowed

Comment: Iterate and count characters? Make an array of counts of the length of your alphabet and increment the count for each character encountered. Then check the ones of interest. Then optimize it by removing the unneeded counters...

Comment: Are you allowed to use `strchr` and `strstr`?

Answer (score 2):

1. For 1, you could use `f[256]` set `f[ch] = 1` for all char in `s1` then check whether `f[ch] == 1` for each char in `s2`
2. For 2, you could use `strstr()` see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
  int f[256];
  memset(f, 0, sizeof(f));

  // check 1
  for (int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    f[s1[i]] = 1;
  for (int i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    if (f[s2[i]] == 0)
      return 0;
  // check 2
  return strstr(s1, s2) == NULL ? 1 : 2;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", check("someaxbxcxdxemm",      "abcde"));
  printf("%d\n", check("someOtherValue",       "abcde"));
  printf("%d\n", check("xyabcdeping",          "abcde"));
  printf("%d\n", check("someaxuxdxlxammabcde", "abcde"));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate structure to check for the individual characters in addition to looking for the substring.

An array of five bools could be used to store the present of each character. e.g:

```
bool chars[5] = {false};

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    char c = str[i];
    switch(c) {
        case 'a':
            chars[0] = true;
            break;
        case 'b':
            chars[1] = true;
            break;
        // include cases for each character you are looking for
    }
}
```

If at the end each entry in the `chars` array is true you know the string contains all characters.

You can do this in addition to what you are already doing to match the substring.

You may also want to look at [some other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12784766/9614249) of checking if a string contains a certain substring.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
int checkabcde(char str[]) {

    // Check if string contains substring "abcde"
    if (strstr(str, "abcde") != NULL) {
        return 2;
    }

    int charCounts[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int length = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;

    // Keep counts of each occurrence of a,b,c,d,e
    for(; i < length; i++) {
        // If "abcde" contains the current character
        if (strchr("abcde", str[i]) != NULL) {
            charCounts[str[i] - 'a']++;
        }
    }

    i = 0;

    // Check if any of the counts for a,b,c,d,e are 0
    for (; i < 5; i++) {
        if (charCounts[i] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Otherwise we must have found at least 1 of each a,b,c,d,e
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At each index in `str` the `sub` loop looks for the substring match. If it is found, 2 is returned. The `found` loop looks to see if that character, str[index], is one of `abcde`. If it is, the matching index in the `check` array is set to space.
After all charecters in `str` have been processed, compare `abcde` to `check`. If there is a match, that matching character is missing in `str`. Return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkabcde ( char str[]) {
    char abcde[] = "abcde";
    char check[] = "abcde";
    int index = 0;
    int match = 1;
    int length = strlen ( str);
    int span = strlen ( abcde);

    while ( str[index]) {
        if ( str[index] == abcde[0]) {
            match = 1;
            for ( int sub = 0; sub < span; ++sub) {
                if ( index + sub > length || str[index + sub] != abcde[sub]) {
                    match = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( match) {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        for ( int found = 0; index + found < length && found < span; ++found) {
            if ( str[index + found] == abcde[found]) {
                check[found] = ' ';
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    for ( int found = 0; found < span; ++found) {
        if ( check[found] == abcde[found]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main( void) {
    char lines[][30] = {
        "someaxbxcxdxemm"
        , "someOtherValue"
        , "xyabcdeping"
        , "someaxuxdxlxammabcde"
        , "vu4ndljeibn2c9n@aiendjba"
        , "dbcaeddeaabcceabcde"
    };

    for ( int each = 0; each < 6; ++each) {
        printf ( "for [%s] result = %d\n", lines[each], checkabcde ( lines[each]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```