# how to add validation mr or mrs before name

Tags: c, algorithm, fgets, c-strings, memcmp

I'm doing validation to input name using Mr or ms or Mrs before name with **do while** statement. what should I fill in the while section?.

is it using strcmp or something else?

coding example

```
do{
    printf("Input Customer's Name [must have Mr. or Ms. or Mrs");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &customerName);
}while(what should i fill here?);
```

Comment: Calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Some libraries add it as a *non-portable* extension. I suggest you instead read the whole line with e.g. `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to parse the string. And remember to check what `sscanf` *returns*. Oh and some nitpicking: `do ... while` is a *statement* not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check substring exists in a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate function that checks whether a name starts with the listed strings.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int start_with( const char *s, const char * a[] )
{
    int success = 0;

    s += strspn( s, " \t" );

    for ( ; *a != NULL && !success; ++a )
    {
        success = memcmp( s, *a, strlen( *a ) ) == 0;
    }

    return success;;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *title[] = { "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", NULL };
    enum { N = 100 };
    char name[N];

    do
    {
        printf( "Input Customer's Name [must have %s or %s or %s: ", title[0], title[1], title[2] );
        name[0] = '\0';
        fgets( name, N, stdin );
        name[strcspn( name, "\n" )] = '\0';
    } while ( !start_with( name, title ) );

    puts( name );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Input Customer's Name [must have Mr. or Ms. or Mrs.: Bob
Input Customer's Name [must have Mr. or Ms. or Mrs.: Mr. Bob
Mr. Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the substring **'Mr.' 'Mrs.'** or **'Ms'** exists in the input string provided by the user or not.
If it exists you can break out of the loop otherwise prompt him/her again.

One thing to note that the substring position in this problem must be **0** (i.e at the *very beginning* of the input string)

You can use **strstr** function as it not only checks for the substring but return a pointer to first occurrence of that also.

e.g

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char customerName[50]; 
    char *titles[3] = {"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."}; 
    char *titlePos; 
    int istitle = 0;

    do{

       printf("Input Customer's Name [must have Mr. or Ms. or Mrs \n");
       scanf("%[^\n]%*c",customerName);

       for(int i=0;i<3 && !istitle;i++){
       // checking if any of the title is present 

          titlePos=strstr(customerName,titles[i]);
          if(titlePos && (int)(titlePos-customerName)==0) {
            istitle=1; // title found 
            printf("CustomerName Consist the Title of %s \n",titles[i]);

        }
    }
}while(!istitle);

  // ... Rest of Your Code

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using strcmp?  ex: while(strcmp(customerName, "Mr ")!= 0 || strcmp(customerName, "Ms ")!= 0 || strcmp(customerName, "Mrs ")!= 0);

Comment: I would suggest rather *strstr* as you need to check for the presence of 'Mr.' 'Mrs.' etc at the very first position in the given input name

Answer (score -1):

If you insist in only changing the `what should i fill here?` in your *coding example*, the most important thing to put in is `getchar()` to consume the leftover newline from the input, otherwise we'd get an endless loop. But normally, one would do this right in the `scanf()` with a format string `"%[^\n]\n"` or `"%[^\n] "` (equivalent).

Besides that, the expression

```
strncmp("Mr.", customerName, 3) &&
strncmp("Ms.", customerName, 3) &&
strncmp("Mrs", customerName, 3)
```

would do.