# Check if there is a string in a string

Tags: string, c99

I was wondering if there is any way to check if a string is included in a string. For example if I have the `string1`: `superman` and `string2`: `per` I would  like to know that `string2` is contained in `string1` and that the first letter of `string2` is in position 2 of the string array of `string1`. Is it possible to do some trick with some already built function to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check substring exists in a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Do you know what it will do if the substring is repeated 2 times in the original string?

Answer (score 0):

You may use strcmp function. 
The strcmp() function compares two strings and returns 0 if both strings are identical. Find more information from the following link.
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

Comment: yes I knew about it but is not what I'm searching for, cause it doesn't see if a word is contained into another, see the example right up