# Is there an "If in" keyword in C like Python?

Tags: python, c, keyword

Could we do something like this?

```
char word = "violet";

if ("vi" in word)
{
  (do something);
}
```

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check substring exists in a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I suspect that the string handling chapter of a C programming book may reveal the answer. Just as the array chapter before it revealed that strings are character arrays `char word[] = ...`.

Comment: Why is this closed as a duplicate of a question asking about finding a *single* character when OP is looking for a longer substring?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, but you could write

```
if (strstr("violet", "vi")){
    // do something
}
```