# Can std::filesystem::path::extension be used for url?

Tags: c++, string, url, c++17, file-extension

Could I use [`std::filesystem::path::extension`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) to extract the extension of a file for which I have an http address in string format?
For local path the discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881646/2436175)

More in general could I use also its siblings methods [stem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem) and [filename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename)?

If not, is there any reliable alternative than doing it manually as spelled out in [the other pre-C++17 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51999/2436175)?

Comment: In general case I do not think so. Note that url has query and fragment which are placed after stem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL specification does not fit with the `filesystem::path` generic path specification. URLs can do things that don't work as intended with `filesystem::path`s. So while it might be able to work in some cases, there is no guarantee that it will work in all of them.

Comment: And there is no alternative to perform this task explicitly, correct?

Comment: @Antonio: The C++ standard library doesn't have a tool for interacting with a URL, no. I'm sure there are libraries out there that can do that.

Comment: Okay, for curl (which is the library I am using) getting the filename might be pretty complicated, the subject is treated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576697/libcurl-how-to-download-url-with-original-filename-equivalent-for-o-remot)